# cout a class object using conversion operator

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

class Complex
{
private:
    double real;
    double imag;

public:
    // Default constructor
    Complex(double r = 0.0, double i = 0.0) : real(r), imag(i)
    {}

    // magnitude : usual function style
    double mag()
    {
        return getMag();
    }

    // magnitude : conversion operator
    operator int ()
    {
        return getMag();
    }

private:
    // class helper to get magnitude
    double getMag()
    {
        return sqrt(real * real + imag * imag);
    }
};

int main()
{
    // a Complex object
    Complex com(3.0, 4.0);

    // print magnitude
    cout << com.mag() << endl;
    // same can be done like this
    cout << com << endl;
}
```

I don't understand how the compiler is resolving to call the conversion operator for `cout << com << endl;`.

I can also have more than one conversion operator in the same class. How will the resolution be done in that case?

Comment: *"I don't understand how the compiler is resolving to call the conversion operator for cout << com << endl;."* What else would you expect it to do?

Comment: Look in the standard header for `cout` at all the standard types it can print. Then realise that it will check each of these until it finds a match. Which your class provides.

Comment: _"I can also have more than one conversion operator"_ then compiler will issue "ambiguity" error (if no single conversion can be considered as "best")

Answer (score 9):

You have declared a conversion operator to `int`. Since this operator is not explicit, the compiler considers it when finding the best overload of `ostream::operator<<`. Keep in mind that C++ compiler always attempts to automatically convert types to find a matching call, including conversion constructors, conversion operators and implicit type conversions.

If you do not want this behavior, then starting from C++11 you can mark the operator as `explicit`:

```
explicit operator int() {
     return getMag();
}
```

Regarding the second part of your question, if there are multiple conversions that are equally good, a compile error is invoked. If you added, say, `operator double`, then as there exists `ostream::operator(double)`, the call would be ambiguous and you would need to cast `com` to Your desired type.

Comment: Does that mean when `cout`ing objects, the compiler looks for conversion operators to inbuilt data types, `int`,`float`,`char`,etc. What if the conversion operator is to convert to an object of some different class? Will then it throw error?

Comment: @InsaneCoder As I've said, why not read the header `iostream` and see for yourself which types have defined conversions for `cout`?

Comment: @InsaneCoder No, it doesn't look for conversions to "inbuilt data types." Just like in any other overload resolution, it gathers all declarations of `operator <<` which it knows, and tries to convert the two arguments (`std::cout` and `com`) to their parameter types. If it succeeds in exactly one case, it uses that. Which means that it can also try a conversion to `std::string`, for example, if you have the string-streaming operator visible.

Answer (score 0):

I supose that the compiler tries to convert to a type for which cout has an overload defined.
If it can be converted to 2 types for which cout has an overload defined you will get a compilation error. 
If you add this function to the class code won't compile:

```
// magnitude : conversion operator
operator float ()
{
    return getMag() + 1;
}
```

To solve that you must do a cast like that:

```
// same can be done like this
cout << "Com: " << (float) com << endl;
```

Comment: Yes, I mean admitted but "a type for which cout has an overload defined" is the good definition. I'll edit my answer.